# cannot access css file from jsp under web-inf

Tags: eclipse, jsp

my my project folder directory is as follows

```
SpringMVCTest/WebContent/WebInf/jsp/index.jsp
```

and

css file is under

```
SpringMVCTest/WebContent/style/main.css
```

My problem is i cannot access css file from index.jsp.I tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/main.css">
```

and others too.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: did you tried `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/main.css">` ?

Comment: yes i have tried it as well and i even tried it now, but doesnot work

Comment: it's not in "../style/", but in "../../style/"

Comment: hmm its not working either....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the following to your servlet-context.xml file 
**Edit**
 
You can find where this file is being read from in your Web.xml file under: At least this is where it is in Spring Mvc 3.1, which is what my projects use.

```
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Your servlet-context.xml file:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /WebContent/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/WebContent directory -->
<resources mapping="/WebContent/**" location="/WebContent/" />
```

Then from your jsp you should be able to use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/WebContent/style/main.css">
```

The above tells spring not to process these static assets through the DispatcherServlet

Comment: I am sure your solution works.But i am a newbie and i dont know where to keep the code.I am using sring mvc and wherever i keep it it gives me error.Further help please.

Comment: Did you create the project from an eclipse template project. If your using the sts tool from spring source they have ready made template. Here is one on github from spring source. https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase